# convert a dataframe to a numeric variable?

Tags: r, class, dataframe, numeric

I have a a variable with  data.frame format and with size (m by n) and I want to convert it to a (m*n by 1) numeric variable. How can I do that? for example having variable "x1" with class of  "data.frame" and size (4*5)

```
x1<-                
104.89  44.09   66.82   75.55   64.04
NA         136.91   60.57   62.29   64.01
NA         NA   87.18   66.76   80.19
NA         NA   NA  NA  NA
```

I want to convert "x1" to variable "x2" as below with size (20*1) and class of "numeric"

```
x2 <- 104.89    44.09   66.82   75.55   64.04       NA  136.91  60.57   62.29   64.01       NA         NA   87.18   66.76   80.19       NA         NA   NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
c(t(x1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like your use case is a matrix with values only in one corner, you can use `upper.tri`. E.g.

```
df=read.table(textConnection('
    104.89  44.09   66.82   75.55   64.04
    NA         136.91   60.57   62.29   64.01
    NA         NA   87.18   66.76   80.19
    NA         NA   NA  NA  NA'))
temp <- df[upper.tri(df)]
temp[!sapply(temp, is.na)]

[1] 44.09 66.82 60.57 75.55 62.29 66.76 64.04 64.01 80.19
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use "textConnection" ?

Comment: that was just to make the example reproducible